# How to use algolia not query in flutter

Tags: flutter, algolia

I'm using algolia in flutter.

I need a query that doesn't contain a specific string.
In SQL, for example, "where category NOT value" query, I want to use NOT query in Alogolia.

I searched for algolia DOCS, but it doesn't work properly.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/
I refer to this page of the DOCS.

My Code

```
AlgoliaQuery query = algolia.instance
    .index(index)
    .query(search)
    .filters('NOT category : $category')
    .setHitsPerPage(limit);
```

I made my query as it says in DOCS, but it doesn't work. Is there any other problem?

My English may not be enough to understand properly. If you don't understand my writing, please leave a comment and I'll answer it.

Thank you for reading it. Have a nice day!

Comment: do you use this package https://pub.dev/packages/algolia ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the package. Is there anything else I need to set up on the homepage for filtering?

Comment: the package is unofficial btw, and the documentation you shared above is official documentation. there is a chance it is a bug from the package or there is a difference how to write the filters in string

Comment: thank you Alexa! I found the wrong part of the homepage and corrected it. It works normally now. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this category!= $category in the filters